# Which mime type should I use if a POST request has both xml and parameters?

Tags: xml, http, mime-types

for example...

```
 age=18&name=fredbloggs&data=<Subject><course>Computer Science</course><module id="778"/></Subject>
```

Should I URL encode the payload? My scenario has spaces, quotes user input etc?

Edit:

I am sending from a Google App Engine App to a windows Azure MVC2 app, both apps do the same thing. So when I recieve a request in one I forward it to the other to keep them in sync. Params are nececarry to authenticate the request, the xml data will be associated with an account so I cannot split it into more requests. 
Its odd, my problem is that my data seems to get corrupted enroute to the Azure app. Some elements are replicated, others disappear, i thought the content type may have had something to do with it.

Comment: Can you give some more info, are you sending this to a server with ajax for example.

Comment: This seems like a _really_ bad idea for accepting data. You can split those components out to two different query string parameters and get the same effect. If you have a more complex graph, then I'd suggest making a post with data.

Answer (score 0):

POST data does not need to be encoded. Also you do not define mime-type for the request, only for HTTP response.

---

### UPDATE

There are 2 different concepts here:

- Is sending un-encoded HTML or XML tags to server OK as far as **HTTP** protocol is concerned?
- Is sending un-encoded HTML or XML tags to server OK in **ASP.NET**?

Answer to first one is: **YES**.

Answer to second one is: **NO** (unless you override this behaviour in your code or config) since **ASP NET** assumes you are sending cross-site scripting data and **it deems it potentially dangerous**.

To fix this, **ideally you should JSON instead of XML** or escape your XML.

Comment: So my example is perfectly valid?